# How to trigger bootstrap collapse in Angular 2/Typescript

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript

Let's say I've this **panel**. I want to be able to expend/collapse it, depending on the selected value of a dropdownlist.

```
<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
    <div class="well">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the **dropdownlist**.

```
<select id="state" name="state"
        [(ngModel)]="stateId"    
        (change)="onChange($event.target.id, $event.target.value)"
        class="form-control">
        <option *ngFor="let r of statesList"
            value="{{ r.id }}">{{ r.name }}
        </option>
</select>
```

This is the **event handler**. And, if a state is selected, expends the panel. Otherwise, collapse the panel.

```
//Events
onChange(id: string, deviceValue: string) {
     if (id == "state") {
        if (deviceValue) {
            //expend the panel...
        }
        else{
            //collapse the panel...
        }
     }
}
```

using **Jquery**, I could just do something like: `$("#collapseExample").collapse();`.

How to get the samething in `Angular/Typescript`?.

Comment: Are you using bootsrap angular library?

Comment: No. I didn't know that there's one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The bootstrap will show div if you add `in` class and it will hide the div when `in` class is removed.

The basic solution looks something like this.

```
<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample" [ngClass]="{'in': isOpen}">
    <div class="well">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

add a boolean variable to your class.

```
isOpen: boolean;
```

and set it according to your business constraints.

```
 onChange(id: string, deviceValue: string) {
              if (id == 'state') {
                  if (deviceValue) // {
                      //expand the panel...
                      this.isOpen = true;
                  }
                  else {
                      //collapse the panel...
                      this.isOpen = false;
                  }
              }
          }
```

However, I would advice you o create a custom directive which can be implemented throughout the solution and you can avoid writing `[ngClass]="isOpen ? 'in' : ''"` everwhere.
You can use your own directive such as

```
<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample" [btCollapse]="isOpen">
```

**Update**: with support for animation.

```
<div id="demo" class="block" [style.height]="height + 'px'" #my>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </div>

<select id="state" name="state"
        [(ngModel)]="stateId"    
        (change)="onChange($event.target.id, $event.target.value, my.scrollHeight)"
        class="form-control">
        <option *ngFor="let r of statesList"
            value="{{ r.id }}">{{ r.name }}
        </option>
```

**Component.ts**
declare a new variable in class.

```
height = 0;

onChange(id: string, deviceValue: string, height: number) {

      if (id == 'state') {
          if (deviceValue == '1') {
              //expand the panel...
              this.height = height;
          }
          else {
              //collapse the panel...
              this.height = 0;
          }
      }
  }
```

don't forget to add the style in inline component style or in a shared css file.

```
styles: [`
    .block {
      overflow: hidden;
      -webkit-transition: height .5s;
      transition: height .5s;
    }
  `]
```

Comment: it's working. Where's the animation? the transition is kind of brutal. Lol!

Comment: @Richard77 I agree mate. There is no out of the box support for animation. I read they are working on i. You'll need some CSS and bit of js code to work it out. Check this plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/VLQ4Izy4VBZdm71UcRWZ?p=preview

Comment: I'm a little confused. Should I replace `class="collapse"` with `class="card card-block card-header block"`?

Comment: Yes. Removing collapse class is important as bootstrap `collapse` css style will hide the div. To avoid behavior conflict with bootstrap class, we have used a new class called 'block'. Replace `collapse` by `block` as style is defined for `block`. you may ignore and remove `card card-block card-header ` classes.

Comment: Sorry, it took long to accept your answer. In fact, I've a better understanding of angular now. It works fine. Thanks so much.

Comment: Glad I could help. I've had faced similar issue so could help you with this one.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 5 will show div if you add `in` and `show` class and it will hide the div when these classes are removed.

This worked for me.

```
<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample" [ngClass]="{'in': isOpen, `show` : isOpen}">
    <div class="well">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```